# Two identities with binomial coefficients

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I found two interesting identities with binomial coefficients on wikipedia. I'm wondering how can I prove them with combinatorial interpretation and still no idea. They seem nice so I suppose combinatorial argument should not be very difficult, but I can be wrong of course:

> 1) $$\sum_{m=0}^{n}{m\choose j}{n-m\choose k-j} = {n+1 \choose k+1}$$
>
> 2) $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{r\choose m+k} {s\choose n-k}={r+s\choose m+n}$$

I would be very grateful for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second is a form of [Vandermonde’s identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity), of which there’s a combinatorial proof at the link.

For the first, imagine choosing $k+1$ numbers from the set $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$; there are $\binom{n+1}{k+1}$ ways to do this. Let the numbers chosen be $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_k$ in increasing order. Suppose that $a_j=m$; there are $\binom{m}j$ ways to choose the $j$ numbers $a_0,\dots,a_{j-1}$ from the set $\{0,\dots,m-1\}$, and $\binom{n-j}{k-j}$ ways to choose the $k-j$ numbers $a_{j+1},\dots,a_k$ from the set $\{m+1,\dots,n\}$. The lefthand side of the identity just sums over the possible values of $m$.

Comment: Thank you, that's brilliant! But for the second I don't see it. In a given link there it is possible to choose $0$ elements (not only, also: $1,2,...,m-1$) to the first set in sum, and here we can only choose $\ge m$ elements to the first set. I think it's a complication.

Comment: @xan: You’re welcome! Let $\ell=m+k$ and $p=n+m$. Then $$\binom{r}{m+k}\binom{s}{n-k}=\binom{r}\ell\binom{s}{p-\ell}\;,$$ and $$\binom{r+s}{m+n}=\binom{r+s}p\;.$$ Since the sum is really taken over all integer values of $k$, with $\binom{n}k=0$ when $k>n$ or $k<0$, you now have the form of Vandermonde’s identity at the link.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer other than to echo Brian; but I believe the source for both of these is the book Concrete Mathematica, chapter 5. The book does things with binomials and sums of binomials that some consider unnatural (such as giving definition to $\binom{-4}{k}$; but is very excellent.